# Made a ginger carrot soup with coconut milk but accidentally made it too salty, how do i fix it?

Tags: salt, soup, ginger, carrots

I made a ginger carrot soup with coconut milk but accidentally made it too salty, how do i fix it?

From some google searches - one said to put raw potatoes to absorb the salt. I am not sure if that will work for the soup as it is a thick carrot soup. Adding water would make it watery. Does anyone have any other methods that would work for me? I would like to keep the soup thick.

Thank You

Edit - the butternut squash worked for me!

Comment: Related: [Soup is too Salty!](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/372/15)

Comment: potatoes can usually help soak up some of the saltiness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steam a head of cauliflower, puree it. Add it to the soup. You might also consider some squash or sweet potato puree.

Comment: Or to keep the integrity of the original soup... just increase the amount of everything in your original recipe except the salt. If that's too much work, following the same train of thought as mfg, butternut squash would probably be a really great choice too.

Comment: @Jay I assume the OP is interested in looking to supplement the ingredients more gradually. If they are just looking for advice on addressing saltiness [then this is a duplicate](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/372/15)

Answer (score 3):

I made chili recently and a tip was to peel a potato and let it sit in there and it would pull in the salt, then just remove the potato.  Haven't tried the technique personally though.

Comment: I have done this before in some bean soups I've made where I went a little overboard with the bacon.  I had to replace some of the broth/liquid after removing the potatoes

Answer (score 2):

Sour cream! I just tried it, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I once overloaded a little too much chicken stock in my homemade tomato soup. I found a good large tin of coconut milk made all the difference. plus it was creamy and highly delicious. Problem solved (with an added cup or two or water).Salt down to a minimum.