# Reclaiming a salty curry

Tags: salt, curry

I often read that salt is added 'to taste' - and I try to keep adding salt until my curries taste right.

However, on occasion my fingers are too big for my pallete, and the dish becomes overly salty. Is there a way to save a salty curry?

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/372/67

Answer (score 5):

Add more potatoes--they absorb the salt.  As would rice or pasta.

Comment: I suppose potatoes have the advantage of being easily removable?

Comment: @jidl they are! I have the same salt problem all the time. If you're making curry with coconut milk, adding more of that often helps as well and tends to be a quicker fix.

Answer (score 1):

I normally just add more water, and then maybe more potatoes to make it a bit thicker again. Since you're usually adding to taste, it shouldn't be so overly salty that you can't rescue it with some more water or even more of any ingredients you've added.

You can also add sugar or lemon. Either should be fine in small amounts for a curry.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an acid will help do disguise there being a bit too much salt in foods.