# Is there a salt antidote?

Tags: salt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix food that got extra salty?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/255/how-to-fix-food-that-got-extra-salty)

Is there any way to resurrect a dish if you put too much salt into it ?  I know you could double up all other ingredients to dilute the salt, but if you don't have this option is there anything that tends to counteract salt ?

Comment: Yep - looks like a dupe. I'd vote to close but not delete (if I could) so people searching for "too much salt" will find their way to that question (which only shows up if searching "too salty")

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact dish, a possible solution I have found (and tried) is to add potatoes to the dish, leave for a while (30 mins or so) then remove.  They are meant to absorb the salt somewhat.  It didnt work for me however.

What is the dish you are having problems with?  If it is something with a sauce (e.g. Stew) I have before had to strain it to remove some sauce and then add more stock/water to dilute it back down to your desired consistency.

Comment: … "it didn't work for me however". Then why are you recommending it? It doesn't actually work for anyone...

Comment: @derobert: I've made something like this work. You end up with about twice as much stew by the time you're done though.

Comment: @Joshua right, you can always add more of everything else (or even just one other thing), and dilute it out. Add enough potatoes, and eventually it won't be too salty (of course, it won't be much else, other than potatoes).